# LibreOffice calc | How can I bring all entries of different rows into one column?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a lot of different column entries per row. And thousands of rows.

Example ( "|" starts a new column)

> 1st row: car | wash | shirt
>
> 2nd row: house | roof
>
> 3rd row: human | animal | technic | plant
>
> ...

How can I bring all entries of different rows into one column?

Example

> car
>
> wash
>
> shirt
>
> house
>
> roof
>
> ...

Comment: Related: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=56505 (didn't try it myself...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `car` is in A1:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,A1:D3)
```

then Data > Text to Columns.